# How to draw background webgl with texture

Tags: web-applications, webgl

I am new to webgl, and I am stuck with this weird problem.

I try to load a texture and draw it as a background of the canvas.
I only need to draw the background once.
So logically I only need to call my function drawBackground() once
this is the snippet of the problem for full code you can view source here 
http://www.csupomona.edu/~lannguyen/WebGl%20Project/bg.html

```
function webGLStart() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson05-canvas");
            initGL(canvas);
            initShaders();
            initBuffers();
            initTexture();

            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
            drawBackground();
        }
```

when I do the code above, it doesn't work. My canvas just went black. Assuming my drawBackground function works fine.

```
function tick() {
        requestAnimFrame(tick);
        drawBackground();
    }


    function webGLStart() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson05-canvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();
        initTexture();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        tick();
    }
```

when I do this, it works, and I have no idea why I have to called tick and requestAnimateFrame(tick), this looks like recursion to me. 
But if I just want to draw once I don't see why I need to constantly drawing it.

Any helps or explanation would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you make some asynchronous calls for fetching resources in some of these:

```
initShaders();
initBuffers();
initTexture();
```

Then when you invoke drawBackground() only once, loading of some resources is still in progress.